# Mule Expression Language and Global Functions to filter records

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a common function that to be used by multiple dataweave transformations so I want to write that as a MEL global function.

I configured my global functions file -

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language>
            <import class="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils"></import>
            <global-functions file="global_expressions.mvel">
            </global-functions>
        </expression-language>
    </configuration>
```

then I have a global_expressions.mvel file where I want a function like -

```
def filterE1Records(route,type){
                    if(type == 'COR'){
                        return (route >= '${min.route}' and route <= '${max.route}');
                    } else if(type == 'NONCOR'){
                        return ((route >= '${min.route}' and route <= '${max.route}') == false and route != '${ndsin.route}');
                    } else if(type == 'NDS'){
                        return route == '${ndsin.route}';
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
```

The above function with property placeholders doesnt work i.e. none of the records pass through. But If I hard code values then I see records filtering as expected -

```
def filterE1Records(route,type){
                    if(type == 'COR'){
                        return (route >= 10000 and route <= 15000);
                    } else if(type == 'NONCOR'){
                        return ((route >= 10000 and route <= 15000) == false and route != 15001);
                    } else if(type == 'NDS'){
                        return route == 15001;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
```

If I remove that single quote ' around property to make it number, then DW code fails at runtime.

Any idea how to make this comparison work?

Thanks.

Comment: From your question, it is unclear if your problem is due to the placeholders not being resolved or to the fact tests only work with string based comparison. You say that using `code >= 10000` works but when you remove `'` it doesn't, which sounds contradictory. Are you sure placeholders are resolved in `global_expressions.mvel`?

Comment: Thank for taking look @DavidDossot Is there a way to find out if placeholders are resolving property in `global_expressions.mvel` file? I am sure and verified if i put placeholder in dataweave directly like p('min.route') then it resolves properly which means properties are configured properly. I dont think I can debug in expression file.   I mean `route >= 10000` works but `route >= '${min.route}'` doesnt work for the same input records.

Comment: I don't understand why you quote the placeholder? Assuming it resolves, you want to use `route >= ${min.route}` otherwise you will be performing a string comparison, not number.

Comment: Also whatever you can do in Java, you should be able to do in MEL, so you should be able to use `System.out` or even create a SLF4J logger and use it, just to debug and see if you get a value in `${min.route}`

Comment: Thanks I tried and got property not resolved error, Not sure how I overlooked it earlier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Based on the discussion in comments, I'm going to assume that property resolution does not work in imported MEL files.

You could load these different properties either in a bean via Spring setter injection, or in a `java.util.Properties` object using Spring's utilities, then look them up with:

```
app.registry.myConfigBean.minRoute
```

or:

```
app.registry.myConfigProperties['min.route']
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it seems like properties do not load in `global_expressions.mvel`, even though they are accessible properly in dataweave and rest of the mule.  Now I changed the function definition to   `def filterE1Records(route,type,cmin,cmax,ndsin)` and from dataweave I call function like   `payload filter (filterE1Records($.ROUTE as :number, 
      flowVars.RecordType,
      p('min.route'),
      p('max.route'),
      p('ndsin.route')
)`.